# exercise from eloquent javascript listTo Array: why isn't the value of list null globally

Tags: javascript

Why does the value of list remain unchanged globally? shouldn't it be null?

```
let list = {value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: null}};

function listToArray(list){
    let array = [];
    while( list != null)
    {
        array.push(list.value);
        list = list.rest;
    }
    return array;
}
```

why is the global array1 changed after passing it through the function below,
If the local variable array in the function is used to reference it?

let array1 = [1,2,3];

function reverseArrayInPlace(array){

for(let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length/2); i++){

```
  let temp = array[i];

  array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];

  array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
```

}

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is list supposed to be?

Comment: Javascript has no list object, so if you have a list of something you should be using an array already. What is `list`, and what is `list.rest` and `list.value`?  Why do you expect `list` to be null?  And unless `list` is null when passed in, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: this is an exercise from the text eloquent JavaScript that converts a nested  object to an array. The  exercise is in the chapter - data structures: objects and arrays. the list is the nested object with keys being "value" and "rest". rest holds the nested object whose keys are also value and rest, till rest is null

Comment: when you access or change `list` variable in the method, local variable `list` is used instead of the global variable.

Comment: @pseudobbs no you don't.If list is null an empty array is returned

Comment: @gp is this for only objects? I wrote a code to reverse an array and the array's new value globally was the reversed form.

Comment: @zizu, initially the local variable `list` was holding whatever object you passed while invoking the method. But when you do `list = something`, you are changing the local variable reference. In your case the local list variable holds reference to main or nested object however the global list variable still holds the original reference. It's like global list is still on the root object but local list variable reference changes from root object to nested object and so on in the loop and to null at end of the loop. Hope it clarifies or let me know.

Comment: @gp look at my edit, why didn't array1 stay the same after passing it through the function? array is the local reference. Thanks for the follow up

Comment: `x = obj; x.propxyz = new_val` here x and obj both hold reference to the same object. so changing the property using x or obj, is updating property of the same object. Same is the case with array `x = arr;` x[0] or arr[0] point to the same index of the same array instance. Don't confuse this with  the list example. that is: `local_list = global_list;` they point to the same object however when you do `local_list = null_or_another_obj;` you are changing local_list variable reference so not global_list still points to the old object but local_list points to null or whatever you assign to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable list object with value and rest is different from the parameter list used in the function. If I remove the parameter, you get what you expected.

```js
let list = {value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: null}};

function listToArray () {
  let array = [];
  while( list != null)
  {
    array.push(list.value);
    list = list.rest;
  }
  return array;
}

let array = listToArray();

console.log( 'list : ', list );
```

Here is your second example :

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3];

function reverseArrayInPlace (array) {
  
  // Here array is pointing to array1
  
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length/2); i++){
   
    let temp = array[i];
    
    // What is happening here is that you are modifying directly whats in array
    // by affecting something to an index of it => array[ i ].
    // Since array is pointing on array1, array1 is getting modified
    array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];

    array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
    
  }

}

reverseArrayInPlace ( array1 );

console.log( array1 );
```

If I use slice before doing anything, array1 will stay the same :

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3];

function reverseArray ( array ) {
  
  // array.slice() is used to copy the array, array is now pointing to a copy of array1
  array = array.slice();
  
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length/2); i++){
   
    let temp = array[i];
    
    // Since array is now a copy of array, it is not modifying the original one
    array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];

    array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
    
  }

}

reverseArray ( array1 );

console.log( array1 );
```

Comment: look at my edit and tell me why array1 changes globally after passing it through the function reverseArrayinPlace?

Comment: Because you are doing the reverse "in place". That means you are not creating a copy of the array before reversing it. The function is using a temporary variable to let you do that in place. Thats why the original array is changing. I will edit to add your example.